# Get text using WebScraping in Laravel 2022 with DomCrawler

Tags: laravel, web-crawler, domcrawler

```
<span class="paperbuzz-source-name" id="paperbuzz-source-pdf">
    Visualizações em PDF
     <div class="paperbuzz-count-label" id="paperbuzz-count-pdf">
       <i class="icon-pdf" aria-hidden="true"></i> 8 <--- *** I NEED THIS INFOROMATION ***
    </div>
</span>
```

I am trying to get an information using Symfony's DomCrawler:

`$downloads = $crawler->filter('div#paperbuzz-count-pdf')->text();`

also I tried:

`$downloads = $crawler->filter('#paperbuzz-count-pdf')->text();`

And returns:

`InvalidArgumentException: "The current node list is empty"`

Is there a way to get that information?

But it returns empty

Comment: Please provide HTML in text format. not a picture. - https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Also this is happening because NULL or an empty string is being passed to the crawler. Your logic of getting the HTML node list is the issue. - Please provide all of the code required.